# Insert Quotation marks in URL

Tags: php, url, url-routing

I have a URL that looks like:

```
example.com/profile.php?id=1
```

I want to dynamically generate the URL by taking username from the form input in the database's id field. Like :

```
example.com/profile.php?id=username
```

This link give errors.If I use below link than it works

```
example.com/profile.php?id="username"
```

But , I am facing problem in anchor tag.My Code :

```
     <a href="contributor-profile.php?id=<?PHP echo "$data['id']";?>">
           <h4 class="contributor-name">
                  <?PHP echo $data ['name'];?>
             </h4>
     </a>
```

I have also used urlencode fuction but it is not working.

```
<a href="profile.php?id=<?PHP echo urlencode($data['id']);?>">
   <h4>
          <?PHP echo $data ['name'];?>
     </h4>
   </a>
```

Comment: _"This link give errors."_ It shouldn't, that's a perfectly valid link. I'll wager that you're building a subsequent SQL query with string concatenation and it isn't quoted (like `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $id`) so it only works when you explicitly pass it quotes.

Comment: This further implies that you are vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Instead of building queries with string concatenation, use [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). See [**this page**](https://phptherightway.com/#databases) and [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for some good examples.

Comment: If you want to pass the quotes in the URL, put it on the outside of the php brackets, not inside. The ones inside just tells the echo that it's a parseable string.  However, I agree with Alex that your error is not due to the URL.